# Converting from ClientSession to String and back

Tags: strings, parsing, haskell

I have a data structure called `ClientSession` which I convert to a `String` separated by `|` for each element and back to the data structure.

```
 18 data ClientSession = ClientSession                                                                                                                 
 19     { sec      :: Int                                                                                                                              
 20     , nsec     :: Int                                                                                                                              
 21     , username :: String                                                                                                                           
 22     , dbid     :: Integer                                                                                                                          
 23     , uuid     :: Int                                                                                                                              
 24     , prand    :: Int                                                                                                                              
 25     } deriving (Ord, Eq)                                                                                                                 
 26                                                                                                                                                    
 27 instance Show ClientSession where                                                                                                                  
 28     show (ClientSession                                                                                                                            
 29          { sec = s                                                                                                                                 
 30          , nsec = ns                                                                                                                               
 31          , username = un                                                                                                                           
 32          , dbid = db                                                                                                                               
 33          , uuid = ud                                                                                                                               
 34          , prand = pr}) = intercalate "|" ls                                                                                                       
 35         where ls = [show s, show ns, un, show db, show ud, show pr]
```

Then I have a set of functions to `read` that string and create a `ClientSession` from the result. The problem is that this set of functions are so ugly that I lay sleepless at night.

I'm looking for feedback on how to make this code more Haskell. It doesn't feel Haskell to me, it feels like I have solved it in another language and then just ported the code straight off. Like when you translate a natural language in Google Translate.

I have thought of different solutions. Maybe I could use template Haskell, or `Typeable/Generics` type classes in some way, or chain the reading using `>>=`, or something similar.

I'm still new to Haskell, I've used it on my spare time very little over a couple of years.

```
 37 fromString :: String -> Maybe ClientSession                                                                                                        
 38 fromString ss = fromParts $ endBy "|" ss         
 ...
 74 fromParts :: [String] -> Maybe ClientSession                                                                                                       
 75 fromParts (s:ns:un:db:ud:pr:[])                                                                                                                    
 76     = newSessionM (readMaybe s) (readMaybe ns) (Just un) (readMaybe db) (readMaybe ud) (readMaybe pr)                                              
 77 fromParts _ = Nothing                                                                                                                              
 78                                                                                                                                                    
 79 newSessionM :: Maybe Int                                                                                                                           
 80             -> Maybe Int                                                                                                                           
 81             -> Maybe String                                                                                                                        
 82             -> Maybe Integer                                                                                                                       
 83             -> Maybe Int                                                                                                                           
 84             -> Maybe Int                                                                                                                           
 85             -> Maybe ClientSession                                                                                                                 
 86 newSessionM (Just s)                                                                                                                               
 87             (Just ns)                                                                                                                              
 88             (Just un)                                                                                                                              
 89             (Just db)                                                                                                                              
 90             (Just ud)                                                                                                                              
 91             (Just pr) = return $ newSession s ns un db ud pr                                                                                       
 92 newSessionM _ _ _ _ _ _ = Nothing                                                                                                                  
 93                                                                                                                                                    
 94 newSession :: Int -> Int -> String -> Integer -> Int -> Int -> ClientSession                                                                       
 95 newSession s ns un db ud pr = ClientSession                                                                                                        
 96     { sec = s                                                                                                                                      
 97     , nsec = ns                                                                                                                                    
 98     , username = un                                                                                                                                
 99     , dbid = db                                                                                                                                    
100     , uuid = ud                                                                                                                                    
101     , prand = pr}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if your `username` contains a bar `'|'`, you won't be able to parse the output back. So be sure to check for this.

Since you're already using a parser, it's much easier to read the whole `ClientSession` using the parser instead of splitting the string and merging the values manually.

First let's define two helper functions:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.Functor
import Data.List
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as P

parseInt :: (Read a, Integral a) => ReadP a
parseInt = read <$> munch1 isDigit <* P.optional (char '|')
```

This one reads one or more digits, consumes `'|'` if there is one, and converts the digits into a number. (Combinator `<*` runs two actions sequentially, but keeps only the result of the first one.)

```
parseNotBar :: ReadP String
parseNotBar = munch (/= '|') <* P.optional (char '|')
```

Similarly tihs second function reads a string until it hits `'|'`, consumes the `'|'` optionally and returns the string.

Then it's easy to construct a `Read` instance. The parser library already has a handy function `readP_to_S` that converts a parser into a `ReadS` function:

```
instance Read ClientSession where
    readsPrec _ = readP_to_S parseClientSession
      where
        parseClientSession :: ReadP ClientSession
        parseClientSession =
            ClientSession <$> parseInt <*> parseInt <*> parseNotBar
                          <*> parseInt <*> parseInt <*> parseInt
```

or more shortly

```
instance Read ClientSession where
    readsPrec _ = readP_to_S $
            ClientSession <$> parseInt <*> parseInt <*> parseNotBar
                          <*> parseInt <*> parseInt <*> parseInt
```

---

Note: The last part is similar to what you have done in your `newSessionM`. Realizing that `Maybe` is an `Applicative` instance you could have written

```
newSessionM s ns un db ud pr
    = ClientSession <$> s <*> ns <*> un <*> db <*> ud <*> pr
```

instead. This generalizes it to any `Applicative`, not just `Maybe`, so it can be used on `Maybe` as well as `ReadP` or any other applicative parser, for example as

```
parseClientSession =
    newSessionM parseInt parseInt parseNotBar
                parseInt parseInt parseInt
```

However, using `<$>` and `<*>` makes the notation usually short enough so that we use the combinators directly without the need to define such helper functions.

Comment: Now that's the Haskell way to do it! :) Thanks for taking time to explain! I clearly have much to learn.